# Silex namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, silex

I'm still quite new to namespaces and struggle to get my head around how to use them. I'm using Silex Microframework and trying to set up my folder structure. So far I have:

```
cms/
  ACP/
    Controller/
      HomeController.php
    View/
  Front/
    Controller/
      HomeController.php
    View/
      Template/
        page.php
      home.php
  app.php
  bootstrap.php
```

I'm trying to load the HomeController in the Front/Controller folder. In my app.php file I am calling the controller for home.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

$app->get("/", "cms\Front\Controller\HomeController::index");
$app->get('/test', function() {
    return new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response("Test successful");
});

return $app;
```

If I go to `/test` in the browser it works fine. However when I go to `/` then I get an error.

> InvalidArgumentException in ControllerResolver.php line 153:
>
> Class "cms\Front\Controller\HomeController" does not exist.

I've defined `cms` as a namespace in composer.json and in HomeController I have

```
<?php namespace cms\Front\Controller;

class HomeController {
    
    public function index() {
        return "Hello World, I'm the front page!";
    }
    
}
```

I've also tried moving the `HomeController.php` file directly into the `cms` directory, changing the namespace in the file to just `cms` and then running `$app->get("/", "cms\HomeController::index");` and it still doesn't work. I get the same error that doesn't exist.

Here is my composer file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.1",
        // ...other requirements
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/var-dumper": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "cms": "cms/"
        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to get this working? I can't seem to find anything on the Silex site or Google. Can someone please help me get my head around namespaces and how this works?

Comment: I am not familiar with Silex, but off the top of my head, what happens when you prefix the second argument in the `get()` method with a back slash? Eg. `"\cms\Front\Controller\HomeController::index"`  I'm wondering if it has to be a fully qualified name.

Comment: Nothing, makes no difference. Silex is built on Symphony 2, so if you're familiar with that it should be the same, or very similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add your source folder into the composer autoloading (https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"Acme\\": "./"}
}
```

In your case the path "./" should work (have not tested), if not you should try to put `cms` folder into a folder like `src` and set the path to "src/"

Remember to run `composer dump-autoload` to regenerate the `autoload.php`

Comment: There we go, that did it. The code I found was using psr-0, not psr-4. I changed it from 0 to 4 and it worked. Thank you.